# Finding all descendandts in tree

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a df like:

```
d = {'Parent': ['abc', 'abc', 'def', 'mno'], 'Child': ['def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'pqr']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and would like to get a df like:

```
d2 = {'Ancestor': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'mno'], 'Descendant': ['def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'pqr']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d2)
```

where `abc` and `mno` are the only ancestors and the rest are listed as descendants to their respective ancestor.

So far I have tried `networkx` but without any luck.

EDIT: example only showing three tiers but tree structure can be any number of tiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using newtorkx with directed graphs:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

d = {'Parent': ['abc', 'abc', 'def', 'mno'], 'Child': ['def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'pqr']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dG = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Parent', 'Child', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Ancenstor':[[i for i in nx.ancestors(dG,i) if i not in df['Child'].tolist()][0] for i in df.Child],
          'Descendent':df['Child']})

df2
```

Output:

```
  Ancenstor Descendent
0       abc        def
1       abc        ghi
2       abc        jkl
3       mno        pqr
```